# How can I increment a int field in my database if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: php, html, sql

So, to summarize my problem, when the user is inputting a form, I have a little checkbox that when checked, it should add +1 to the current value in the database, but I'm just not getting hold of what logic to use

### Database

Table - users

Fields

- idUsers - PK (int)
- uidUsers (username)
- emailUsers
- pwdUsers
- user_type
- shifts_done - Field that needs to be incremented everytime the checkbox is checked during form submission

### HTML Checkboxes

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="shifts_done" name="shifts_done"/>
                </div>

                <!-- Submit form -->
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="create-report" type="submit">Create</button>
```

### PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['shifts_Done'])) {

$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['uid']);
    $shifts_done=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['shifts_done']);


$increment = " UPDATE users SET shifts_done = '".$shifts_done."' WHERE uidUsers = '".$username."'";

}
```

### Edit - Rest of the form

```
<?php
require 'dbh.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['shifts_done'])) {

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $shifts_done = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['shifts_done']);


    $increment = "UPDATE users SET shifts_done = shifts_done + 1 WHERE uidUsers = '" . $username . "'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $increment);
}

if(isset($_POST['create-submit'])) {


    //Declaração de variáveis
    $username = $_POST['uid'];
    $origin = $_POST['origin'];
    $destination = $_POST['destination'];
    $transport = $_POST['transport'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $date=strtotime($_POST['date']);
    $date=date("Y-m-d",$date);
    $time=strtotime($_POST['time']);
    $time=date('H:i:s',$time);



    //inserts new shift
                $sql = "INSERT INTO shifts (name, origin, destination, transport_number, status, date, time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    header("Location: ../shifts.php?error=sqlerror");
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $username,$origin, $destination, $transport, $status, $date, $time);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    header("Location: ../shifts.php?newrecord=success");
                    exit();

                }


}
```

Now I don't really know if the update query is right because of the username being used as a variable to update the other field, but I also don't really know how to do the increment part I intent.

Any help in both these regards would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: are you expecting a auto increment

Comment: please do update your question with a snap of db and please mention the required field that need to be updated. So that can provide a clean code

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Thank you, will do. Sorry about that.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha Updated as required, thank you

Comment: give me couple of minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to rewrite your query as:

```
$increment = "UPDATE users SET shifts_done = shifts_done + 1 WHERE uidUsers = '".$username."'";
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work. Could you please take a look at my updated question where i have included the database?

Comment: It should work. Are you sure you __execute__ your query?

Comment: @PedroDias I can see you found your answer .

Comment: @u_mulder I have executed the query yes, could this be caused by some kind of error when I'm submitting the form with the other data? I can provide the code for that aswell.

Comment: You `input` has name `shifts_done` and you're checking `$_POST['shifts_Done']`. These are different keys.

Comment: @u_mulder Yes I did notice it and changed it when I was using your query, but it still doesn't seem to do the trick. I will edit the post with the whole part that inserts the form. (Ignore not using mysqli_escape_string() yet, I still need to change that)

Comment: Output result of `mysqli_query($conn, $increment);`, if it is `false` - then your query failed and you have to find out why.